# Python: Recipe Program

Tags: python, recipe

I'm doing a Recipe program project for GCSE Computing. It stores recipes in .txt documents and then when requested it will open and present the information for those to read.

At this moment in time, it stores the recipe at the top of the .txt file and the ingredients at the bottom. It runs thorugh heading1 for the recipe and splits it up for presenting. Then it should go through heading2 and look through each column, ingredients, weight and measurement. Then using a for loop, will go through the lists and present the ingredients together with their respective weight and measurement.

Code is as below:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        Recipe Holder
# Purpose:      Hold recipes
#
# Author:      Ashley Collinge
#
# Created:     25/02/2013
# Copyright:   (c) Ashley Collinge 2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def menu():
    print "Recipe Holder"
    print "Use the numbers to navigate the menu."
    print ""
    print ""
    print "1) View Recipes"
    print "2) Add Recipes"
    print "3) Delete Recipe"
    print ""
    choice_completed = False
    while choice_completed == False:
        choice = raw_input("")
        if choice == "1":
            choice_completed = True
            view_recipe()
        elif choice == "2":
            choice_completed = True
            add_recipe()
        elif choice == "3":
            choice_completed = True
            delete_recipe()
        else:
            choice_completed = False

def view_recipe():
    print ""
    print ""
    mypath = "/recipe"
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join
    onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir("H:/Recipes/recipes") if isfile(join("H:/Recipes/recipes",f)) ]
    a = -1
    for i in onlyfiles:
        a = a +1
        print a, i
    print ""
    print "Type in the number of the recipe you would like to view, below and press enter."
    print ""
    choice = input("")
    import os, sys
    print onlyfiles[choice]
    something = str(onlyfiles[choice])
    directory =  "recipes" + "\\" + something
    from itertools import takewhile, imap
    with open(directory) as f:
        items = list(takewhile("heading1".__ne__, imap(str.rstrip, f)))
        print "Recipe for " + directory
        for h in range(len(items)): #following three lines to take the list of recipe and split it by line in to instructions then display
            print str(h)+". "+str(items[h])
    def getColumn(title,file):
        result = []
        global result
        with open(file) as f:
            headers = f.readline().split(',')
            index = headers.index(title)
            for l in f.readlines():
                result.append(l.rstrip().split(',')[index])
            return result

    ingredients = (getColumn("ingredients",directory))
    weight = (getColumn("weight",directory))
    measurement = (getColumn("measurement",directory))
    print directory
    print "Ingredients"
    for i in range(len(ingredients)):
        print ingredients[i]+" "+weight[i]+" "+measurement[i]
    input("")

def delete_recipe():
    print "Delete Recipe"
    print "Type in the number of the recipe you would like to delete, below and press enter."
    mypath = "/recipe"
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join
    onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir("H:/Recipes/recipes") if isfile(join("H:/Recipes/recipes",f)) ]
    a = -1
    for i in onlyfiles:
        a = a +1
        print a, i
    choice = input("")
    import os, sys
    print onlyfiles[choice]
    something = str(onlyfiles[choice])
    directory =  "recipes" + "\\" + something
    os.remove(directory)

menu()
```

Text file is as below:

```
Recipe As now
Put sugar in bowl
heading1
ingredients,weight,measurement,
Sugar,100,grams
heading2
```

I get the following as an error:

```
raspberry_pie - Copy (8).txt
Recipe for recipes\raspberry_pie - Copy (8).txt
0. Recipe As now
1. fhgje
2. fe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Recipes\Recipe Program.py", line 96, in <module>
    menu()
  File "H:\Recipes\Recipe Program.py", line 24, in menu
    view_recipe()
  File "H:\Recipes\Recipe Program.py", line 69, in view_recipe
    ingredients = (getColumn("ingredients",directory))
  File "H:\Recipes\Recipe Program.py", line 65, in getColumn
    index = headers.index(title)
ValueError: 'ingredients' is not in list
```

Comment: Just to say, kudos for firstly learning proper skills in GCSE computing, and secondly for coming to a great place to learn it!

Comment: Is there a formatting error in your code as presented? `getColumn` doesn't appear to ever be called from outside of itself (which seems a strange thing in itself).

Comment: Could you please explain the semantics behind "Recipe As" and the "headingX". My understanding is that heading would be the step and then the ingredients and their proportaions are listed underneat. I.e

Heading = Whip the eggs |
ingredients,weight,measurement |
2 eggs,100g,1 cup

Comment: @HennyH looking at Ashley's previous questions, he hasn't engaged in the slightest after dumping a question on the community. Not the best way to learn methinks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to resort to putting most errors or issues I have with programming, on to forum websites for extra support, as the teacher who is supervising the controlled assessment doesn't know Python very well, and I can't ask any other teachers as it is a controlled assessment.

Comment: @HenryGomersall Yes, I forgot to leave white space between the end of the function (I think) and the calling of it

Comment: @AshleyCollinge I suggest you edit the post so it is correct!

Comment: @HennyH I'm not sure what you mean.. But the "Recipe As" was just something I put in as text to see if it worked properly. As you can see in the error part, just above that, is the start of the recipe, I need to change the loop slightly, h+1, so it starts at 1

Comment: @AshleyCollinge Since this is an academic exercise, let's go through the process of debugging it. That list that `ingredients` isn't in, where does that come from? What is the contents of the string that is parsed to create it?

Comment: def getColumn(title,file):
        result = []
        global result
        with open(file) as f:
            headers = f.readline().split(',')
            index = headers.index(title)
            for l in f.readlines():
                result.append(l.rstrip().split(',')[index])
            return result  

This searches the text file and looks for the title of the first column, "ingredients" in the text file

ingredients,weight,measurement,
Sugar,100,grams

@HenryGomersall

Comment: You don't need to copy the code. It was a conceptual question; I know what you *think* it does. You should work out what it *actually* does. What is the string that you first call `split()` on (that is yielding the list without `ingredients` in)?

Comment: splits the titles line in the text file, by comma into a list
@HenryGomersall

Comment: @AshleyCollinge does it? Are you sure? Have you inspected the string to make sure?

Comment: Sorry, no, that's the issue, that's what It is meant to do. It, tries to find "ingredients" in the text file, but it can't @HenryGomersall

Comment: @AshleyCollinge Look, I know what the problem with you code is, but I'm not going to just tell you because then you'll learn precisely nothing. I'm trying to guide you through finding the answer yourself. So, I suggest you start by finding out what the `split()` method is actually trying to split. That should give you an indicator.

Comment: @HenryGomersall It's splitting the wrong line?

Comment: @AshleyCollinge right. So something to be aware of when opening a file using the context manager (the `with open(file) as f:` notation), is each time you do that you are back at the beginning of the file...

Comment: @HenryGomersall If i move the ingredients columns to the top it would work. But then further up the program would break

Comment: @HenryGomersall Do you think it would be possible to use something like this: import os
done = "notdone"
while done =="notdone":
    for line in file('Raspberry Pie.txt', 'r'):
        if line.startswith('ingredients'):
            print line
            done = "done"

to specify the line i need it to read from?

Comment: @AshleyCollinge I would actually suggest restructuring your code entirely, and moving all the parsing to the same loop, which is only done once. Currently you're trying to parse the whole file for every column which, as well as being inefficient, you're also discovering is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rewritten version of your program up above. The only thing that does not work is adding recipes. If you need further help, please post a comment on this answer to that effect. You will need to create a subdirectory alongside this program called *recipes* (or whatever you set the `SUBDIR` variable name to be). To test, make sure you put your `raspberry_pie.txt` file in that folder before running.

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:         Recipe Holder
# Purpose:      Hold recipes
#
# Author:       Ashley Collinge & Stephen Chappell
#
# Created:      11 July 2013
# Copyright:    (c) Ashley Collinge 2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import takewhile, zip_longest
from os import listdir, remove
from os.path import join, isfile, splitext, basename

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SUBDIR = 'recipes'

def main():
    print('Recipe Holder')
    print('Use the numbers to navigate the menu.')
    options = {'1': view_recipe,
               '2': add_recipe,
               '3': delete_recipe}
    for key in sorted(options, key=int):
        print('{}) {}'.format(key, get_title(options[key].__name__)))
    while True:
        choice = input('> ')
        if choice in options:
            options[choice]()
            break

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def view_recipe():
    path = get_file('Type in the number of the recipe you '
                    'would like to view and press enter.')
    print('Reciple for', get_name(path))
    with open(path) as file:
        lines = filter(None, map(str.strip, file))
        for step in enumerate(takewhile('heading1'.__ne__, lines), 1):
            print('{}. {}'.format(*step))
        columns = OrderedDict((name.strip(), [])
                              for name in next(lines).split(','))
        max_split = len(columns) - 1
        for info in takewhile('heading2'.__ne__, lines):
            fields = tuple(map(str.strip, info.split(',', max_split)))
            for key, value in zip_longest(columns, fields, fillvalue=''):
                columns[key].append(value)
    ingredients = columns['ingredients']
    weights = columns['weight']
    measurements = columns['measurement']
    assert len(ingredients) == len(weights) == len(measurements)
    print('Ingredients')
    for specification in zip(ingredients, weights, measurements):
        print(*specification)

def add_recipe():
    raise NotImplementedError()

def delete_recipe():
    path = get_file('Type in the number of the recipe you '
                    'would like to delete and press enter.')
    remove(path)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def get_file(prompt):
    files = tuple(name for name in
                  (join(SUBDIR, name) for name in listdir(SUBDIR))
                  if isfile(name))
    for index, path in enumerate(files, 1):
        print('{}) {}'.format(index, get_name(path)))
    print('Type in the number of the recipe you '
          'would like to view and press enter.')
    return files[int(input('> ')) - 1]

def get_name(path):
    return get_title(splitext(basename(path))[0])

def get_title(name):
    return name.replace('_', ' ').title()

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: offtopic. Was reading your code and found it quite educational for me. Could you please share why you used filter(None, ) instead of iter() to create iterator?

Comment: @MjH `filter(None, ...)` is the same as `filter(bool, ...)`. In might make more sense to think of this in terms of `filter(lambda line: len(line) > 0, ...)` or `filter(lambda line: len(line.strip()) > 0, file)`. The purpose of using `filter` instead of `iter` is that (1) all lines should be stripped of whitespace at the start and end of the string and (2) empty lines should not be processed. If `lines = map(str.strip, file)` had been used, there is a possibility that completely blank lines would be encountered when iterating over the map. `filter(None, ...)` skips those blank lines.